# Persisting Authentication Token in ASP Net core API?

Tags: c#

Much like the title says, I have a web-app/api that requires authentication from the SpotifyAPI, this returns an AuthCode which I then exchange for a token. Currently, when the Token is returned, I keep it in a static class so I can use it within any method of the class - here is a pseudo code of what its like

```
class ApiClass {

    public index(){
        //Authenticate with spotify
    }

    public callback(string code){
        Token token = auth.exchangeToken(code);
        StaticClass.Token = token;
    }

    public getData(){
        return SpotifyApiCall(StaticClass.token);
    }
}
```

i can't imagine having a static class would be the best way to go about these things. Something to note is when each new user access the page, they will have to authenticate.. which means I would have to clear the token when the data is done? just so another user doesnt use the same token and get the data about the previous user, right?

Im not looking for code but looking for the correct way to store persist tokens.

Comment: Usually you store the token at client side and the storage handels about expiration and so on and usually every time you pass the stored token to the api and the api will internally call spotify to authenticate/authorize, dont write class as static but inject as singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your token on the `client-side` (cookie, sent them in headers), and implement authorization attribute which decrypt your token from request and then checks for permissions, on `backend` it can be stored on persistence storage(NoSQL, SQL DB).

Comment: I would use the .net membership authentication and then you can use sliding expiration on the cookie.  This will keep resetting the expiry each time the user interacts with the website, if I understand correctly that is what you are looking to achieve?  Also you can change it absolute expiration if required if you need it to expire at a specific time.